# Arduino Uno Starter kit project 12

Tags: arduino

I am making the Arduino Knock lock and the piezo buzzer is making noise. I was wondering if that is normal. Here is the code.

```
/**
 * @file     knock_lock.ino
 * @author   Phi Luu
 * @date     September 06, 2016
 *
 * @brief    Arduino Projects Book - Project 12: Knock Lock
 *
 * @section  DESCRIPTION
 *
 * Uses the Piezo buzzer to make a secret locking mechanism in order to keep
 * intruders out.
 */

#include <Servo.h>
Servo ServoMotor;

// Required hardware I/O connections
const byte PIEZO_PIN = A0;     // the pin piezo buzzer connected to
const byte SWITCH_PIN = 2;     // the pin switch connected to
const byte YELLOW_LED_PIN = 3; // the pin yellow LED connected to
const byte GREEN_LED_PIN = 4;  // the pin green LED connnected to
const byte RED_LED_PIN = 5;    // the pin red LED connected to
const byte SERVO_PIN = 9;      // the pin servo motor connected to

// Global constants
const unsigned short BAUD_RATE = 9600;
const byte QUIET_KNOCK_VAL = 30;
const byte LOUD_KNOCK_VAL = 50;
const byte MAX_NUM_KNOCK = 5;

// Global variables
byte switch_val;
byte knock_val;
boolean is_locked = false;
byte num_knocks = 0;

void setup() {
    ServoMotor.attach(SERVO_PIN);
    pinMode(SWITCH_PIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(YELLOW_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(GREEN_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RED_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
    // unlock the box first
    digitalWrite(GREEN_LED_PIN, HIGH);
    ServoMotor.write(0);
    Serial.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
}

void loop() {
    if (is_locked == false) {
        switch_val = digitalRead(SWITCH_PIN);

        if (switch_val == HIGH) {
            LockTheBox();
        }
    } else {
        knock_val = analogRead(PIEZO_PIN);

        // require MAX_NUM_KNOCK valid knocks
        if ((num_knocks < MAX_NUM_KNOCK) && (knock_val > 0)) {
            if (CheckForKnock(knock_val) == true) {
                num_knocks++;
            }
            Serial.print("Need ");
            Serial.print(MAX_NUM_KNOCK - num_knocks);
            Serial.println(" more knock(s)");
        }

        if (num_knocks >= MAX_NUM_KNOCK) {
            UnLockTheBox();
            // reset num_knocks
            num_knocks = 0;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Changes the LEDs and turn the servo to unlock the box.
 */
void UnLockTheBox(void) {
    // change the is_locked value
    is_locked = false;
    // indicate on LEDs
    digitalWrite(RED_LED_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GREEN_LED_PIN, HIGH);
    // rotate the servo to 0 degree
    ServoMotor.write(0);
    // print a message on the Serial Monitor
    Serial.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
    // allow time for the servo to completely move
    delay(20);
}

/**
 * Changes the LEDs and turn the servo to lock the box.
 */
void LockTheBox(void) {
    // change is_locked value
    is_locked = true;
    // indicate on LEDs
    digitalWrite(GREEN_LED_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RED_LED_PIN, HIGH);
    // rotate the servo to 90 degrees
    ServoMotor.write(90); // rotate the servo 90 degrees to lock
    // print a message on the Serial Monitor
    Serial.println("ACCESS DENIED");
    // allow time for the servo to completely move
    delay(20);
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a knock is valid or not.
 *
 * @param   a_knock_val   the loudness of the knock
 *
 * @return                true if a valid knock, false otherwise
 */
boolean CheckForKnock(byte a_knock_val) {
    if ((a_knock_val > QUIET_KNOCK_VAL) && (a_knock_val < LOUD_KNOCK_VAL)) {
        digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED_PIN, HIGH);
        delay(50);
        digitalWrite(YELLOW_LED_PIN, LOW);
        Serial.print("Valid knock value: ");
        Serial.println(a_knock_val);
        return true;
    } else {
        Serial.print("Invalid knock value: ");
        Serial.println(a_knock_val);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Piezo buzzers make noise by design and intention. Can you elaborate on when it's making noise and how it sounds, as well as why you think there's something wrong with it making noise in that manner?

Comment: This is more appropriate to https://arduino.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Did you accidentally connected the piezo element to **pin 0** instead of **pin A0**? As I recall, pin 0 is used for the serial communication to the host PC, so I imagine you might hear some strange noises if you did that. Pin A0 is on the left side; pin 0 is on the bottom right.